# Accessing Salesforce and querying from a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, salesforce, soql

I'm trying to implement a feature into a rails app where a user can enter a "referral id" (a custom field in salesforce) and the app will retrieve the status of their referral. I've been trying to set up the REST API Oauth2 authentication for it but I can't figure out how to run my query against salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `restforce` for querying a Salesforce API. It's simple to setup and provides OAuth token authentication.

https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce

Comment: I ended up using `restforce` at first I tried `databasedotcom` but it was far too complex for what I was doing.